# Just do it rebus

Tags: mathematics, word, rebus

> $\Large n = \Large a^{-1}\cdot e^{\frac{\huge it}{\huge s}}$

It is a catchy phrase.

Comment: Saw  the title and thought it must be nike... Guess I was sort of close :P

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, doing some mathematical manipulation:

> $n=a^{-1}\cdot e^{\frac{it}{s}}\Rightarrow an=e^{it/s}\Rightarrow\log(an)=\frac{it}{s}\Rightarrow s\log(an)=it$

So I guess the answer is

> it's a slogan.

Comment: I argue it should be $\color{white}{s\ln(an)=it\text{ (since the base of the log is currently undefined}}$ (highlight to see spoiler).

Comment: @boboquack As a pure mathematician, I use `log` for natural logarithm. `ln` is an abomination.

Comment: Is there a specific reason as to why you used implication-arrows? Aren’t most manipulations equivalence mutations?

Comment: +1 @Rand... Good one. However we understood log as for logarithm(that is for base 10 or other bases) and   **ln** as for natural logarithm (to the base _e_)

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay As Rand already explained, actual mathematicians use log to mean natural log.

Comment: It really depends on context. Mathematics: log = base e. CS: log = base 2. Many other fields of research: log = base 10.

Comment: @Gareth That's not *exactly* what I said. I'm not snobby enough to say applied mathematicians aren't actual mathematicians ;-)

Comment: I *think* most applied mathematicians use log to mean natural log too. You get more base-10 logs in engineering, though.

Comment: @Randal'Thor $log$ is an abomination because it lacks clarity. As a member of the STEM community, clarity should be a *very* high priority for all of us. You may find it distasteful, but you (and many others) will never be confused about the base if I write $ln$ or $lg$ or $log_{10}$.

Comment: @jpmc26 except I have never seen the `lg` notation before...

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix it means $\log_2$

Comment: @jpmc26 The notation $log$ is an abomination because it is typeset like the product of three variables $l$, $o$, and $g$. Please use `\log` to get $\log$. Similarly for $\ln$ and $\lg$. (And BTW, $\lg$ is used in some fields to mean $\log_{10}$ rather than $\log_{2}$.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Pardon me. As a programmer, I don't use LaTeX very much. Thanks for the tip!